# Hiding Password field content from users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know if its possible for me to do something from the following :

1) Replace the source code visible in view source , with an image , or nothing at all.

2) Hide the `value attribute` of `<inpt type="password" ....>`  tag , so that the password entered by the user is not visible to anyone .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Entered passwords will never be visible to anyone except user himself..

Comment: Why do you want to hide the password in the browser? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Any markup that your server sends to the browser is accessible to the end user. There's no way to "hide" such markup completely

Answer (score 4):

1. You can minify your HTML to make it slightly unreadable, but it's trivial to unminify it. You can't do anything further to "remove" or "hide" it.
2. You mean to hide the `value` attribute after the user types something in, or to hide the value sent from the server? If the former, you could use JavaScript to extract the value as it's typed into some variable and replace the value with gibberish. If the latter, then the obvious answer is to not send that value.

Comment: Minification will not be helpful as user can easily inspect the element and browser renders those minified elements already..

Comment: My main intent is to remove the attribute for the input field , so that the password is not visible . It can be done at any time , be it page load or after user enters password in a field or anytime else .

Comment: No, you can't remove the attribute. You could extract its value on change and store it in some JS variable, then replace the value attribute's content with gibberish, but that will get messy fast.

Comment: I see this being done in Facebook's change password dialog . After typing in anything in the current , new and confirmation password fields , I can't see any value after doing inspect element .

What might be happening there ?

Comment: That's just your browser. Firebug on Firefox doesn't show a `value="input"` attribute in the inspector for any input entered after the page loaded for any type of field, password or no. I presume other browsers are similar. Edit: Confirmed same for Chrome.

Comment: By moving the value from the input control, you are moving away from a tried and tested way of doing things and attempting to roll your own solution. This is usually more insecure and will still be visible when it is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 3):

View source is a representation of static HTML, so if you create any element dynamically, it will not be displayed in view source.

**Note:** *These fields will still be accessible using dev tools.*

Following is a sample code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3g72byk/)

```js
function submit() {
  var uName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
  var uPass = document.getElementById("txtUserPass").value;

  console.log(uName, uPass);
}

function addPasswordField() {
  var passInput = "<input type='password' id='txtUserPass' />";
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += passInput;
}

(function() {

  addPasswordField();
})()
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <input type="text" id="txtUserName">
</div>
<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hide source code in a browser since that is how these things are built. The web is an open platform and developers working with the web need to have the view source functionality while working on their project(s). May I ask why you feel the need to hide the source code and the password?

Comment: When a user is trying to login , he provides credentials and clicks the login button.

At that time , performing an inspect element provides an input type tag with the value containing the password entered by the user .

I'd like to work around this functionality , so that the password field contents cannot be revealed via Inspect Element

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that is done. As far as I know, there is no way you can do this. Even on a site like Gmail, you're allowed to view your password in said manner. You're better off leaving that functionality open. I sometimes use this technique just to double check that I'm typing in the right password.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question: No. This is how browsers are designed and there are lots of other ways to request the page to see the source. For example, you could use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the traffic passing between the server and the browser.

As for the second question...why are you trying to hide the password?

Using the password input type will prevent anyone from seeing the password on the screen. so I assume this is to stop the data being viewed in transit?

If you want to secure your connection between the client and the server, you should consider using a secure (https) connection. Thanks to [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) this is free, so it is no longer a costly option.

Answer (score -2):

Try using:
input[type="password"] {-webkit-text-security: disc !important;}

I hope that helps.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does the style you've shared influence how the markup is displayed in "View source"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).